# Numbering Corollaries

Tags: numbering, theorems

I am trying to number corollaries of a theorem in a specific way. For example, if the last theorem was Theorem 7, I would like that a corollary of this theorem appears as Corollary 7.1.

Is there a way to do so?

Here is how theorems and corollaries are currently declared.

```
\newcommand{\srcsizeeight}{\@setfontsize{\srcsize}{8pt}{8pt}}
\newcommand{\mytextsize}{\srcsizeeight}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\newtheorem{thm}{\mytextsize Theorem}{\bf}{}

\newtheorem{cor}{\mytextsize Corollary}{\bf}{}
```

Comment: Something like `\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]` should help and then `\begin{corollary}{Foo} ...\end{corollary}` after the relevant `theorem` code

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Where is your answer :-)? I want voted you.

Comment: @Sebastiano: This is a clear duplicate of some other question. Probably no need to write an answer here unless there are more issues that are not shown here

Comment: Thanks Christian. Unfortunately Corollary 0.1 is produced with this code instead of Corollary 7.1. In other words, I need to keep memory of the last theorem stated.

Comment: @DanCat: If this is the case. show your compilable code. Is the theorem number reset by chapter/section and the corollary used in a new chapter/section? Then `0.1` is pretty likely

Comment: @DanCat: Please add it to your post above, all in an compilable document, not only fragments, not as comment

Comment: `\bf` is an outdated macro

Comment: @DanCat: Please add the compilable document, not only fragments and format it as code by pressing `CTRL-K` or hitting the `{}` button